# Angular2 using threejs Orbitcontrols

Tags: angular, three.js, angular-cli

I'm trying to use threejs exemple inside my angular (cli) 2 app.

So i have installed threejs :

```
npm install three --save
```

then added typings :

```
npm install @types/three --save-dev
```

Finally my component looks like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-testthreejs',
    templateUrl: './testthreejs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./testthreejs.component.css']
})
export class TestthreejsComponent implements OnInit {
//
}
```

With this i can use some functionality from THREE without any problem.

I would like to use some of the exemple available in node_modules/three/examples/js/ and more precisely OrbitControl. The typings give me the autocompletion in visual studio code : 
[image: vscode]

But as soon as i tried to use it i have the following error :

> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_three**.OrbitControls is not a
>   constructor

Is there any way to make available OrbitControls (and other exemples) via some import ?
Should i simply include control.js in my html ?

What's the best way to deal with this ?

Comment: IMO, Grunt (or whatever) your own three.min.js file that includes extras that you'll need such as controls, obj file loading or whatnot rather than NPM install. You could include extras/helpers in script tags, but that's a maintenance nightmare.  Do what makes sense for your project, there's no documentation or specific way to add extras and helpers to three.js.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found a solution :

1- Install OrbitControls via npm :

```
npm install three-orbit-controls --save
```

2- Import THREE and OrbitControls in the component :

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
var OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)
```

I can then do

```
this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera,this.renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: Grunk, can you please help me here? I tried your solution in an Angular-cli environment and when I run the code the error: 'Cannot find name 'requ
ire' appears. It is driving me mad. is your solution still working for you?

Comment: @Dino Yes still working (updated to angular 4). You can find my sample component here : https://pastebin.com/uG0fvs8n (just ignore the API service part)

Comment: Grunk, you are a real star! Thank you, your code helped me to improve mine :) May I be rude and use a bit of your time asking another question about the Three JS library and angular? Do you know how to import and use the PLYLoader.js. It is an untyped js library for THREE so I cannot use  npm install plyloader --save to import it in angular 2. Again thank you for your help. Dino

Comment: no idea sorry. I just have a basic usage of threejs

Comment: Could you please reupload your pastebin. I am getting the same error as @Dino in an Angular-cli environment

Comment: Hi Jason, just saw your question. To fix the problem I have used the line

     `declare const require: (moduleId: string) => any;`

before the line

    `const OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);`

as suggested by Grunk, hope it helps.

Answer (score 14):

NEW APPROACH

just import OrbitControls from example modules

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
```

OLD ANSWER

Try use alternative package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-orbitcontrols-ts

**1. Install package**

```
npm install --save three-orbitcontrols-ts
```

**2. Use in your file**

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three-orbitcontrols-ts';

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: Solid idea, but I have a bunch of attributes I use like saveState that dont appear to exist on this type. does this package need a patch?

Comment: Simple, easy to follow... probably the easiest thing I've followed when it comes to threejs! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

as few of you are experiencing my same problem I have posted this as a answer to make it more visible.

The solution above works but you might get the following error:

> 'Cannot find name 'require'

If this is the case add the line suggested by Grunk:

```
declare const require: (moduleId: string) => any;
```

before the declaration:

```
var OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)
```

Answer (score 2):

See working example of using Angular + Three.js including OrbitControls and ColladaLoader: https://github.com/makimenko/angular-three-examples

Currently, Three.js examples are not included into a module and use them in Angular typescript code could be a little bit tricky. Especially, if you don't want to install additional third-party dependencies. One of solution/workaround could be:

Firstly, include dependencies:

```
three
@types/three
```

Secondly, import in component:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import "./js/EnableThreeExamples";
import "three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls";
import "three/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader";
```

Then use it in code:

```
this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera);
this.controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
this.controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);
```

Hope this could help you to start

Comment: This works when running in `ng serve`, however, when running `ng build --prod` I get `"export 'OrbitControls' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in 'three'`

Comment: Warning message will be visible until “threejs/examples/js” not transformed to support modules (see threejs [#9562](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562)).
Just ignore warning message (ng build --prod should create all necessary and fully working code for you in dist folder).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `three`examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js` tries to install itself on the THREE property of the window, which does not exist just because you did `import * as THREE from `three`.

Answer (score 1):

A monkey patch can also solve this issue:

```
// this should be added in the main file of the application
import * as THREE from 'three';
window['THREE'] = THREE;
import 'three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls';
```

No need to add any *ThreeJS* related script in *.angular-cli.json* file